# Webservice in android is showing Server timeout error

Tags: android, web-services

Trying to call .Net webservice in android for the first time. Webservice is working perfectly in advanced web client chrom extension.

[image]

But in below Android code, its showing server timeout exception.

```
final int DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 200000 * 1000000000 * 1000000000;
            String str;


            progress.setMessage("Please Wait...");
            progress.setIndeterminate(false);
            progress.setCancelable(false);

            progress.show();
            // Make RESTful webservice call using AsyncHttpClient object
            AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
            client.setTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);

            // failed
            client.post("http://10.0.2.2:8080/DService/ServiceSD.svc/LoginUser?Query=login=WT&password=03&includeUserMiscInfo=true",
                    new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {


                        String str;

                public void onSuccess(int i, Header[] headers, byte[] bytes) {

                    try {
                        str = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Returned"
                                + str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        progress.dismiss();

                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                @Override
                public void onFailure(int i, Header[] headers, byte[] bytes, Throwable throwable) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Status code :" + i + "errmsg : " + throwable.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    progress.dismiss();
                }

            }
            );
```

Am I calling the webservice correctly? Any suggestions are welcome. thanks.

Comment: make sure port `8080` is allowed on machine `10.0.2.2` firewall

Comment: My machine firewall is off. I understand that for localhost --> 10.0.2.2 can be used.

Comment: no, for localhost you use `127.0.0.1` but that's not what you want, you want the IP address of the machine hosting the webservice

Comment: my machine is hosting the webservice.

Comment: so put your machine's IP. you can't use localhost or 127.0.0.1 because though android emulator is running on the same machine (PC) , you can't use localhost because that means the webservice is hosted in the emulator which is not the case, so find your PC's IP address and use it in the code

Comment: tried my ip. it shows timeout again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104833/discussion-between-dep-and-yazan).

Comment: Any further suggestions pls?

Comment: Connect to /192.188.0.100:8080 timed out

Answer (score 0):

I removed the port number from my ip and it's working now.